# Selenium WebDriver - Java : How to write webtable data into an excel file in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

:) I am trying to write the web table data into an excel file using Selenium-WebDriver with Java. By the below code I was able to print only the last column data in the excel but not the entire webtable data. Could you please help me out here.....

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import  java.io.*;  
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  

public class WebTableTOSpreedsheet  
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
{     
System.out.println("Hello Dear.....");     
System.out.println();  

WebDriver wb = new FirefoxDriver();          
wb.navigate().to("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"); 
wb.manage().window().maximize();     
System.out.println(wb.getTitle() +" - WebPage has been launched");   

List<WebElement> irows =   wb.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody/tr"));     
int iRowsCount = irows.size();     
List<WebElement> icols =   wb.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/th"));     
int iColsCount = icols.size();     
System.out.println("Selected web table has " +iRowsCount+ " Rows and " +iColsCount+ " Columns");     
System.out.println();      

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D://Software//AutomationPractise//WebTableTOSpreedsheet.xlsx");                                 

XSSFWorkbook wkb = new XSSFWorkbook();       
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wkb.createSheet("DataStorage"); 

for (int i=1;i<=iRowsCount;i++)      
{               
for (int j=1; j<=iColsCount;j++)                    
{           
if (i==1)       
{           
WebElement val= wb.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody/tr["+i+"]/th["+j+"]"));             
String  a = val.getText();            
System.out.print(a);                        

XSSFRow excelRow = sheet1.createRow(i);             
XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(j);                  
excelCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);                 
excelCell.setCellValue(a);  

//wkb.write(fos);       
}       
else        
{           
WebElement val= wb.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]"));             
String a = val.getText();                    
System.out.print(a);                            

XSSFRow excelRow = sheet1.createRow(i);             
XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(j);                      
excelCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);                   
excelCell.setCellValue(a);   

//wkb.write(fos);       
}       
}               
System.out.println();     
}     
fos.flush();     
wkb.write(fos);     
fos.close();     
}
}
```

Output:[Webtable's data write issue in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqtmj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new empty row for each cell in `for (int j=1; j<=iColsCount;j++)` loop. Move `XSSFRow excelRow = sheet1.createRow(i);` to loop iterating over `i`.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= iRowsCount; i++) {
        XSSFRow excelRow = sheet1.createRow(i);
        for (int j = 1; j <= iColsCount; j++) {
```

---

For others, I had to add this to my code to execute properly:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\path\\to\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
```